# Reusing the JDBC connection from Hibernate with Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc

I've searched for a long time on this topic however I cannot find a solution to my specific issue. I am trying to figure out how I can pull the JDBC connection from Hibernate so that I can run a query for generating reports. I am trying to use a JDBC connection since my reports don't map well to the existing Entity situation that we have.

Right now, my application has a bean for a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and a bean for `DataSource`, which is a just a DriverManagerDataSource, both residing in a core configuration file. The problem that I am having is, whenever I try to wire up my DAO to access the JDBC connection by doing something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

private SessionFactory session;

public SystemUsageReportDAO() {
    session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

I simply get a null pointer exception at the constructor line. I've tried all manner of getting the connection from the EntityManagerFactory, however I'm not sure how I can do it. Any advice would be appreciated.

I know that my end goal is to get a `Session` object, and from there I can call `doWork`, however getting to that `Session` is proving quite the task for me.

Comment: Put yourself in Spring's shoes. You need to create an instance of SystemUsageReportDAO and initialize its entityManagerFactory field. Imagine the field is public to make your task easier. How do you proceed? You call the constructor to have an object, then initialize the field of that object, right. So, at the time the constructor is called, what is the value of the field? null, right? Why don't you just execute a native (i.e. SQL query) with the entity manager? Or why don't you simply inject the DataSource, and use a JdbcTemplate to execute SQL?

Comment: Ah ok, I see your point. I'm setting up the constructor before the entityManagerFactory is set up. My goal in not doing those is so I can re-use the JDBC connection that Hibernate already has. If I make a new JdbcTemplate bean that has a data source, I am thinking it's making a new (heavy weight) connection, and I need to make sure to close it when I am done generating reports. I could be terribly wrong though.

Comment: For those who google (and somehow) find this, I just ended up using a JdbcTemplate (as suggested earlier) based off of my DataSource.